# Private Network using Stelllar-core

Tags: stellar-core

I have launched Private Blockchain using latest stellar-core and add inflation also and whenever testing inflation using stellar-sdk then facing following issues:-

result_codes:
{​​ transaction: 'tx_failed',
operations: [ 'op_success', 'op_bad_auth' ] }​​

Please help.